# How to update props correctly in React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to react, wanted to ask if this piece of code is good practice, because I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong but not sure what.

I have a main class component which has an array of packages which consists of width, height etc.

I'm passing this packages array as props to another functional component where I want to update these values. Currently my implementation looks like this:

```
<Card pck={pck} key={pck.packageId}/>



export default function Card(props) {

const widthProperties = useState(0);
props.pck.width = widthProperties[0]
const setWidth = widthProperties[1];

<input type="number" id={props.pck.packageId} className="form-control"
                               value={props.pck.width} 
                               onChange={(e) => setWidth(parseInt(e.target.value))}
                               placeholder="Width" required/>
}
```

It works correctly, but as I said, I believe that I'm not using the `useState` with `props` correctly. Could someone explain what is wrong here? Because 3 lines of code to update props' state looks strange for me.

Comment: **You never directly mutate props.** This `const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);` should be in the parent and passed down to the children like `<Card width={width} setWidth={setWidth} key={pck.packageId}/>`, then used in the Card like `<input value={props.width} onChange={props.setWidth} />`.

Comment: @GG. Ok, understood. Could you help me figure it out. I'm iterating through packages array from class component each time creating a `<Card />` component. So how would that look then? `this.state.packages.map(pck => <Card width={pck.width} ? />` How would the `setWidth` function look like? If i have my packages in classes state object.

Comment: Yes that seems fine. The `setWidth` will probably take an id as argument so you can find the package you want to modify. You will have something like `setWidth = (width, packageId) => { this.setState({ packages: this.state.packages.map(pck => pck.id == packageId ?  { ...pck, width } : pck) }) }`.

Comment: @GG. Seems to be working fine, could you just explain the pck.id moment? I'm getting unresolved variable id, because my package doesn't containt this id variable. But as soon as I change it to my existing pck.packageId it stops working.

Comment: Then yes it should be `pck.packageId == packageId`. Are you sure you passing a correct `packageId` to `setWidth`? You can add a `console.log(width, packageId)` inside `setWidth` to see what's going on.

Comment: Nevermind, was passing incorrect value, thank you for your help!

Comment: @GG. please submit your answer so I could mark this issue as resolved :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You never directly mutate props** like you do here: `props.pck.width = widthProperties[0]`.

To have a correct data flow, `width` and `setWidth` should be in the parent component and passed down to the children, so that the children can update their `width` by calling `setWidth`.

So, since the parent is a class component, you will have something like:

```
class CardsList extends Component {
  state = {
    packages: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('api.com/packages')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => this.setState({ packages: result.items }))
  }

  setWidth = (width, packageId) => {
    this.setState({
      packages: this.state.packages.map(
        pck => pck.packageId === packageId ?  { ...pck, width } : pck
      )
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="cards-list">
        {this.state.packages.map(pck => (
          <Card pck={pck} setWidth={this.setWidth} key={pck.packageId}/>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And a Card component like:

```
const Card = ({ pck, setWidth }) => (
  <input value={pck.width} onChange={e => setWidth(e.target.value, pck.packageId)} />
)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's common to destructure the value and setter function from useState like so:

```
[value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
```

From what I gather from your question, the props.pck.width is the initial value of the input, so you may do something like this:

```
[width, setWidth] = useState(props.pck.width);

<input type="number" id={props.pck.packageId} className="form-control"
value={width} 
onChange={(e) => setWidth(parseInt(e.target.value))}
placeholder="Width" required/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't use `useState` like that. `useState` returns an array of two things:

- The variable you are going to use
- A function which is used to change that variable

So in you case it should look like this:

```
const [widthProperties, setWidthProperties] = useState({}); //Here you can either pass an empty object as an initial value or any structutre you would like.

setWidthProperties(props.pck.width); //Or whatever you want to set it to.
```

Remember never to change the variable manually. Do it only through the function `useState` gives you.